# How to launch `coqide` on Ubuntu?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, coq, opam, coqide

I have installed `coq` and `CoqIDE` via `opam`, following the instructions [here](https://coq.inria.fr/opam-using.html).

As noted in the instruction, each time I have to

> export OPAMROOT=~/opam-coq.8.9.0
>
> eval `opam config env`

before launching `CoqIDE` via `coqide`.

Otherwise, it complains

> Command `coqide` not found.

How to configure my system so that I can launch `coqide` directly via `coqide` each time? Adding the `export` and `eval` commands to `~/.bashrc` and `source ~/.bashrc` does not work for me.

---

Configuration:

- Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, 64-bit
- opam 2.0
- coq 8.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `opam init` that offers to modify your `.bash_profile` with the correct line. This will avoid the need of `` eval `opam config env` `` (or rather `eval $(opam env)` from version 2) in every terminal.

If you use a non-standard `OCAMLROOT`, it seems to me that you must add the appropriate `export OCAMLROOT` line in one of your bash configuration files (and I assume it must be read before the line added by `opam init`).

Comment: Thanks. It works: add the `export OPAMROOT=~/opam-coq.8.9.0` line to `~/.bashrc`. Then run `opam init` to let `opam` modify `~/.bashrc` by appending some configuration to the end of this file (particularly, after the `export` line).